# Pattern matching interview Q

Tags: java, algorithm

I was recently in an interview and they asked me the following question:

> Write a function to return true if a string matches a pattern, false
>   otherwise

Pattern: 1 character per item, (a-z), input: space delimited string

This was my solution for the first problem:

```
static boolean isMatch(String pattern, String input) {
    char[] letters = pattern.toCharArray();
    String[] split = input.split("\\s+");

    if (letters.length != split.length) {
        // early return - not possible to match if lengths aren't equal
        return false;
    }

    Map<String, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    // aaaa test test test1 test1
    boolean used[] = new boolean[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        Character existing = map.get(split[i]);
        if (existing == null) {
            // put into map if not found yet
            if (used[(int)(letters[i] - 'a')]) {
                return false;
            }

            used[(int)(letters[i] - 'a')] = true;
            map.put(split[i], letters[i]);
        } else {
            // doesn't match - return false
            if (existing != letters[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.out.println(isMatch("aba", "blue green blue"));
    System.out.println(isMatch("aba", "blue green green"));
}
```

The next part of the problem stumped me:

> With no delimiters in the input, write the same function.

eg:

```
isMatch("aba", "bluegreenblue") -> true
isMatch("abc","bluegreenyellow") -> true
isMatch("aba", "t1t2t1") -> true
isMatch("aba", "t1t1t1") -> false
isMatch("aba", "t1t11t1") -> true
isMatch("abab", "t1t2t1t2") -> true
isMatch("abcdefg", "ieqfkvu") -> true
isMatch("abcdefg", "bluegreenredyellowpurplesilvergold") -> true
isMatch("ababac", "bluegreenbluegreenbluewhite") -> true
isMatch("abdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba") -> true
```

I wrote a bruteforce solution (generating all possible splits of the input string of size `letters.length` and checking in turn against `isMatch`) but the interviewer said it wasn't optimal.

I have no idea how to solve this part of the problem, is this even possible or am I missing something?

They were looking for something with a time complexity of `O(M x N ^ C)`, where M is the length of the pattern and N is the length of the input, C is some constant.

**Clarifications**

- I'm not looking for a regex solution, even if it works.
- I'm not looking for the naive solution that generates all possible splits and checks them, even with optimization since that'll always be exponential time.

Comment: Well, of course it's possible. Just find all ways of splitting the string into `pattern.Length` substrings and see if any of them fit the pattern. The interesting question is if there's something **better** than that.

Comment: I did that, the interviewer said it wasn't optimal.

Comment: Wouldn't just checking for the presence of each/any char from the pattern in the string suffice?

Comment: There are two things. First parsing the "pattern query". Then the hard part of trying to match patterns with the string.

Comment: Your fourth test case seems odd to me. "t1t1t1" matches the pattern if you let a = b = t1, so why should it be false?

Comment: What is a bruteforce solution exactly? And what is the expected time complexity of an "optimal" solution?

Comment: @genisage the same string can't map to different chars

Comment: @kraskevich generating all possible splits of the length of the pattern and checking against the pattern.

Comment: Is `t1t12t1` a match for `aba`? (As `t1`, aka pattern `a` is a substring of pattern `b`)

Comment: yes, a = t1, b = t12

Comment: I wonder if there's a regex to hack this...

Comment: Step 1., build the suffix tree `tp` of the pattern string. Step 2., build the suffix tree `tin` of the input tree. Step3, try to contract `tin` so its structure is the same as `tp`. I'm wondering if this "contraction" step might be fast (if it exists). Anyway just a wild thought cast away :)

Comment: I'm only thinking aloud here: 1. Take the first character of the pattern and how many times it is repeated, that is, how many copies of the first substring should exist. Then take the first character of the string and count how many times it appears in the string. If this number is less than the copies needed, return `false` immediately. 2. ??? 3. Profit

Comment: @IVlad [Yes, there is](http://ideone.com/OgGayJ). Unfortunately, `("abc", "aabbcc")` would break this solution because of the requirement that different letters must map to different substrings.

Comment: Another thought: maybe a useful example to consider when thinking about the algorithm would be this: `isMatch("abcd", "aaaaaaaaaa") -> true`

Comment: @biziclop Actually suffix trees are helpful for that matter. Take a substring, walk down the tree using it. Count the number of branches that derives from the point you walked down in. This number is the number of repetitions of the given substring (but these repetitions may overlap...). Anyway it's still better than nothing

Comment: In your examples you don't have any repeating characters in your patterns.  Is that just an omission of base cases or do you want a solution that allows them?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas repeating characters are allowed, i.e `aabbcaac` is a valid pattern.

Comment: This is an interesting problem but the exposition is lacking. It's not clear what is meant by "if a string matches a pattern" until the examples at the bottom. A well-written question should start by explaining the problem precisely (with examples) before introducing any code.

Comment: So, was this really for an interview question?  It seems too complicated to be expected to code up a solution on the spot... Unless I just missed the easy answer...

Comment: I was interested in reading more stuff about this problem because it looks interesting, but searching "pattern matching" leads me into a totally different set of problems. Does this class of problems have a more specific name in CS?

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to optimize a backtracking solution. Instead of generating all splits first and then checking that it is a valid one, we can check it "on fly". Let's assume that we have already split a prefix(with length `p`) of the initial string and have matched `i` characters from the pattern. Let's take look at the `i + 1` character.

1. If there is a string in the prefix that corresponds to the `i + 1` letter, we should just check that a substring that starts at the position `p + 1` is equal to it. If it is, we just proceed to `i + 1` and `p + the length of this string`. Otherwise, we can kill this branch.
2. If there is no such string, we should try all substrings that start in the position `p + 1` and end somewhere after it.

We can also use the following idea to reduce the number of branches in your solution: we can estimate the length of the suffix of the pattern which has not been processed yet(we know the length for the letters that already stand for some strings, and we know a trivial lower bound of the length of a string for any letter in the pattern(it is 1)). It allows us to kill a branch if the remaining part of the initial string is too short to match a the rest of the pattern.

This solution still has an exponential time complexity, but it can work much faster than generating all splits because invalid solutions can be thrown away much earlier, so the number of reachable states can reduce significantly.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this is cheating, and I'm not convinced the capture group and reluctant quantifier will do the right thing. Or maybe they're looking to see if you can recognize that, because of how quantifiers work, matching is ambiguous.

```
boolean matches(String s, String pattern) {
    StringBuilder patternBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Map<Character, Integer> backreferences = new HashMap<>();
    int nextBackreference = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
        char c = pattern.charAt(i);

        if (!backreferences.containsKey(c)) {
            backreferences.put(c, nextBackreference++);
            patternBuilder.append("(.*?)");
        } else {
            patternBuilder.append('\\').append(backreferences.get(c));
        }
    }

    return s.matches(patternBuilder.toString());
}
```

Comment: I thought of the same thing myself. I believe it should work out, and it was probably what they were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
Here is my solution.  Based it off of the explanation I made before.

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Combinations;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by carlos on 2/14/15.
 */
public class PatternMatcher {

    public static boolean isMatch(char[] pattern, String searchString){
        return isMatch(pattern, searchString, new TreeMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>(), Sets.newHashSet());
    }
    private static boolean isMatch(char[] pattern, String searchString, Map<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> candidateSolution, Set<String> mappedStrings) {
        List<Integer> occurrencesOfCharacterInPattern = getNextUnmappedPatternOccurrences(candidateSolution, pattern);
        if(occurrencesOfCharacterInPattern.size() == 0)
            return isValidSolution(candidateSolution, searchString, pattern, mappedStrings);
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> sectionsOfUnmappedStrings = sectionsOfUnmappedStrings(searchString, candidateSolution);
        if(sectionsOfUnmappedStrings.size() == 0)
            return false;
        String firstUnmappedString = substring(searchString, sectionsOfUnmappedStrings.get(0));


        for (int substringSize = 1; substringSize <= firstUnmappedString.length(); substringSize++) {
            String candidateSubstring = firstUnmappedString.substring(0, substringSize);
            if(mappedStrings.contains(candidateSubstring))
                continue;
            List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> listOfAllOccurrencesOfSubstringInString = Lists.newArrayList();
            for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < sectionsOfUnmappedStrings.size(); currentIndex++) {
                Pair<Integer,Integer> currentUnmappedSection = sectionsOfUnmappedStrings.get(currentIndex);
                List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> occurrencesOfSubstringInString =
                        findAllInstancesOfSubstringInString(searchString, candidateSubstring,
                                currentUnmappedSection);
                for(Pair<Integer,Integer> possibleAddition:occurrencesOfSubstringInString) {
                    listOfAllOccurrencesOfSubstringInString.add(possibleAddition);
                }
            }

            if(listOfAllOccurrencesOfSubstringInString.size() < occurrencesOfCharacterInPattern.size())
                return false;

            Iterator<int []> possibleSolutionIterator =
                    new Combinations(listOfAllOccurrencesOfSubstringInString.size(),
                            occurrencesOfCharacterInPattern.size()).iterator();
            iteratorLoop:
            while(possibleSolutionIterator.hasNext()) {
                Set<String> newMappedSets = Sets.newHashSet(mappedStrings);
                newMappedSets.add(candidateSubstring);
                TreeMap<Integer,Pair<Integer,Integer>> newCandidateSolution = Maps.newTreeMap();
                // why doesn't Maps.newTreeMap(candidateSolution) work?
                newCandidateSolution.putAll(candidateSolution);

                int [] possibleSolutionIndexSet = possibleSolutionIterator.next();

                for(int i = 0; i < possibleSolutionIndexSet.length; i++) {
                    Pair<Integer, Integer> candidatePair = listOfAllOccurrencesOfSubstringInString.get(possibleSolutionIndexSet[i]);
                    //if(candidateSolution.containsValue(Pair.of(0,1)) && candidateSolution.containsValue(Pair.of(9,10)) && candidateSolution.containsValue(Pair.of(18,19)) && listOfAllOccurrencesOfSubstringInString.size() == 3 && candidateSolution.size() == 3 && possibleSolutionIndexSet[0]==0 && possibleSolutionIndexSet[1] == 2){
                    if (makesSenseToInsert(newCandidateSolution, occurrencesOfCharacterInPattern.get(i), candidatePair))
                        newCandidateSolution.put(occurrencesOfCharacterInPattern.get(i), candidatePair);
                    else
                        break iteratorLoop;
                }

                if (isMatch(pattern, searchString, newCandidateSolution,newMappedSets))
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean makesSenseToInsert(TreeMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> newCandidateSolution, Integer startIndex, Pair<Integer, Integer> candidatePair) {
        if(newCandidateSolution.size() == 0)
            return true;

        if(newCandidateSolution.floorEntry(startIndex).getValue().getRight() > candidatePair.getLeft())
            return false;

        Map.Entry<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> ceilingEntry = newCandidateSolution.ceilingEntry(startIndex);
        if(ceilingEntry !=null)
            if(ceilingEntry.getValue().getLeft() < candidatePair.getRight())
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidSolution( Map<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> candidateSolution,String searchString, char [] pattern, Set<String> mappedStrings){
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> values = Lists.newArrayList(candidateSolution.values());
        return  areIntegersConsecutive(Lists.newArrayList(candidateSolution.keySet())) &&
                arePairsConsecutive(values) &&
                values.get(values.size() - 1).getRight() == searchString.length() &&
                patternsAreUnique(pattern,mappedStrings);
    }

    private static boolean patternsAreUnique(char[] pattern, Set<String> mappedStrings) {
        Set<Character> uniquePatterns = Sets.newHashSet();
        for(Character character:pattern)
            uniquePatterns.add(character);

        return uniquePatterns.size() == mappedStrings.size();
    }

    private static List<Integer> getNextUnmappedPatternOccurrences(Map<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> candidateSolution, char[] searchArray){
        List<Integer> allMappedIndexes = Lists.newLinkedList(candidateSolution.keySet());
        if(allMappedIndexes.size() == 0){
            return occurrencesOfCharacterInArray(searchArray,searchArray[0]);
        }
        if(allMappedIndexes.size() == searchArray.length){
            return Lists.newArrayList();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < allMappedIndexes.size()-1; i++){
            if(!areIntegersConsecutive(allMappedIndexes.get(i),allMappedIndexes.get(i+1))){
                return occurrencesOfCharacterInArray(searchArray,searchArray[i+1]);
            }
        }
        List<Integer> listOfNextUnmappedPattern = Lists.newArrayList();
        listOfNextUnmappedPattern.add(allMappedIndexes.size());
        return listOfNextUnmappedPattern;
    }

    private static String substring(String string, Pair<Integer,Integer> bounds){
        try{
            string.substring(bounds.getLeft(),bounds.getRight());
        }catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println();
        }
        return string.substring(bounds.getLeft(),bounds.getRight());
    }

    private static List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> sectionsOfUnmappedStrings(String searchString, Map<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> candidateSolution) {
        if(candidateSolution.size() == 0) {
            return Lists.newArrayList(Pair.of(0, searchString.length()));
        }
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> sectionsOfUnmappedStrings = Lists.newArrayList();
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> allMappedPairs = Lists.newLinkedList(candidateSolution.values());

        // Dont have to worry about the first index being mapped because of the way the first candidate solution is made
        for(int i = 0; i < allMappedPairs.size() - 1; i++){
            if(!arePairsConsecutive(allMappedPairs.get(i), allMappedPairs.get(i + 1))){
                Pair<Integer,Integer> candidatePair = Pair.of(allMappedPairs.get(i).getRight(), allMappedPairs.get(i + 1).getLeft());
                sectionsOfUnmappedStrings.add(candidatePair);
            }
        }

        Pair<Integer,Integer> lastMappedPair = allMappedPairs.get(allMappedPairs.size() - 1);
        if(lastMappedPair.getRight() != searchString.length()){
            sectionsOfUnmappedStrings.add(Pair.of(lastMappedPair.getRight(),searchString.length()));
        }

        return sectionsOfUnmappedStrings;
    }

    public static boolean areIntegersConsecutive(List<Integer> integers){
        for(int i = 0; i < integers.size() - 1; i++)
            if(!areIntegersConsecutive(integers.get(i),integers.get(i+1)))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean areIntegersConsecutive(int left, int right){
        return left == (right - 1);
    }

    public static boolean arePairsConsecutive(List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> pairs){
        for(int i = 0; i < pairs.size() - 1; i++)
            if(!arePairsConsecutive(pairs.get(i), pairs.get(i + 1)))
                return false;
        return true;
    }


    public static boolean arePairsConsecutive(Pair<Integer, Integer> left, Pair<Integer, Integer> right){
        return left.getRight() == right.getLeft();
    }

    public static List<Integer> occurrencesOfCharacterInArray(char[] searchArray, char searchCharacter){
        assert(searchArray.length>0);

        List<Integer> occurrences = Lists.newLinkedList();
        for(int i = 0;i<searchArray.length;i++){
            if(searchArray[i] == searchCharacter)
                occurrences.add(i);
        }
        return occurrences;
    }

    public static List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> findAllInstancesOfSubstringInString(String searchString, String substring, Pair<Integer,Integer> bounds){
        String string = substring(searchString,bounds);
        assert(StringUtils.isNoneBlank(substring,string));

        int lastIndex = 0;
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> listOfOccurrences = Lists.newLinkedList();
        while(lastIndex != -1){
            lastIndex = string.indexOf(substring,lastIndex);
            if(lastIndex != -1){
                int newIndex = lastIndex + substring.length();
                listOfOccurrences.add(Pair.of(lastIndex + bounds.getLeft(), newIndex + bounds.getLeft()));
                lastIndex = newIndex;
            }
        }
        return listOfOccurrences;
    }
}
```

It works with the cases provided, but is not thoroughly tested.  Let me know if there are any mistakes.

ORIGINAL RESPONSE:

Assuming your string you are searching can have arbitrary length tokens (which some of your examples do) then:

You want to start trying to break your string into parts that match the pattern.  Looking for contradictions along the way to cut down on your search tree.

When you start processing you're going to select N characters of the beginning of the string.  Now, go and see if you can find that substring in the rest of the string.  If you can't then it can't possibly be a solution.  If you can then your string looks something like this

(N characters)<...>[(N characters)<...>] where either one of the <...> contains 0+ characters and aren't necessarily the same substring.  And whats inside of [] could repeat a number of times equal to the number of times (N characters) appears in the string.

Now, you have the first letter of your pattern matched, your not sure if the rest of the pattern matches, but you can basically re-use this algorithm (with modifications) to interrogate the <...> parts of the string.

You would do this for N = 1,2,3,4...
Make sense?

I'll work an example (which doesn't cover all cases, but hopefully illustrates)  Note, when i'm referring to substrings in the pattern i'll use single quotes and when i'm referring to substrings of the string i'll use double quotes.

isMatch("ababac", "bluegreenbluegreenbluewhite")

Ok, 'a' is my first pattern.
for N = 1 i get the string "b"
where is "b" in the search string?
**b**luegreen**b**luegreen**b**luewhite.

Ok, so at this point this string MIGHT match with "b" being the pattern 'a'.  Lets see if we can do the same with the pattern 'b'. Logically, 'b' MUST be the entire string "luegreen" (because its squeezed between two consecutive 'a' patterns) then I check in between the 2nd and 3rd 'a'. YUP, its "luegreen".

Ok, so far  i've matched all but the 'c' of my pattern.  Easy case, its the rest of the string.  It matches.

This is basically writing a Perl regex parser.   ababc = (.+)(.+)(\1)(\2)(.+). So you just have to convert it to a Perl regex

Comment: Why on earth would you assume that all patterns are the same length?

Comment: you can do that to save on processing in special cases.  Its MUCH quicker to check that first.  and in his examples, he has a lot of them.

Comment: You are making an invalid assumption. Take that example: `dogchairchair`  and the pattern `abb`. The input matches the pattern, yet it's 13 char-long

Comment: That is the second case.

Comment: `If your pattern is 3 long, then the string has to be a string length has to be divisible by 3` - false: `aba` and string = '1235123`, length 7.

Comment: Listen, you guys dont understand that the first case is a heuristic to save on processing in an easy case.  Case 2 is the general solution.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas We do understand it.

Comment: Maybe you're on to something, but as it stands, your answer is not at all clear. Please take some time to make it clearer and then repost.

Comment: your 2nd case wouldn't work for pattern: abc and input: redgreenblue

Comment: It looks like the brute force solution to me. You have to try all values of `N`, and then recurse for each one.

Comment: In a brute force method, if your pattern was length X, then you would just break your string into every possible way that has X tokens and check against the pattern. Basically for every every possible way to break the string up, you run in through the OP's solution.  This is clearly not that.

Comment: `Logically, 'b' MUST be the entire string "luegreen" (because its squeezed between two consecutive 'a' patterns)` - how would you detect this efficiently in code? Anyway, it's clearer now. I removed my downvote.

Comment: You were correct to say it was unclear.  I wasn't being lazy, I just have to get going soon AND i'm supposed to be coding things i'm paid to code ;-).
Suppose you have a structure that can map each letter in a pattern to a substring in the string (including indexes).  Now, you've mapped the first letter of your pattern, move on to the second.  Do a check to see if there are any other unmapped patterns between your current index and the next known (mapped) index.  In such a case, that means that the entire <...> must be  mapped to you.

Comment: what about blueblackgreenblue? black and blue both start with b.

Comment: in that case, you would find that 'a' = "b" doesn't make sense because you are forced to say 'b' = "lue" then that is contradicted by the fact "lackgreen" !== "lue".  I have to go pick up my girlfriend from the train, but do ask more questions if you ahve them.  Another case that is not intuitive is when you have more than 3 b's in the string.

Comment: I'm not sure how fast it would be in practice or if there's a better solution, but it sounds on the right path so far.  +1.

Comment: I'm dumb, I'm driving and I realized its a regex parser. ababc = (.+)(.+)(\1)(\2)(.+). So you just have to convert it to a Perl regex

Comment: That will almost work. The problem is that with the regex idea you don't account for the constraint that all of the named patterns have to be different. (also, I'm not sure if you can have more than 9 backreferences)

Comment: Good observation. You would have to afterwards check to make sure that constraint is true and rewrite the regex so that it doesn't match what was already matched and retry. And yes, I don't know of a regex that allows more than 9 matches, but in theory, there is no reason you couldn't write one or write one with the constraint built in instead the hack I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You could improve on brute force by first assuming token lengths, and checking that the sum of token lengths equals the length of the test string.  That would be quicker than pattern matching each time.  Still very slow as number of unique tokens increases however.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample snippet of my code:

```
public static final boolean isMatch(String patternStr, String input) {
    // Initial Check (If all the characters in the pattern string are unique, degenerate case -> immediately return true)
    char[] patt = patternStr.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(patt);
    boolean uniqueCase = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < patt.length; i++) {
        if (patt[i] == patt[i - 1]) {
            uniqueCase = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (uniqueCase) {
        return true;
    }
    String t1 = patternStr;
    String t2 = input;
    if (patternStr.length() == 0 && input.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (patternStr.length() != 0 && input.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (patternStr.length() == 0 && input.length() != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int count = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    String match = "";
    // first read for the first character pattern
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        sb.append(chars[i]);
        count++;
        if (!input.substring(count, input.length()).contains(sb.toString())) {
            match = sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length()).toString();
            break;
        }
    }
    if (match.length() == 0) {
        match = t2;
    }
    // based on that character, update patternStr and input string
    t1 = t1.replace(String.valueOf(t1.charAt(0)), "");
    t2 = t2.replace(match, "");
    return isMatch(t1, t2);
}
```

I basically decided to first parse the pattern string and determine if there are any matching characters in the pattern string. For example in "aab" "a" is used twice in the pattern string and so "a" cannot map to something else. Otherwise, if there are no matching characters in a string such as "abc", it won't matter what our input string is since the pattern is unique and so it doesn't matter what each pattern character matches to (degenerative case).

If there are matching characters in the pattern string, then I would begin to check what each string matches to. Unfortunately, without knowing the delimiter I wouldn't know how long each string would be. Instead, I just decided to parse 1 character at a time and check if the other parts of the string contains the same string and continue adding characters to the buffer letter by letter until the buffer string cannot be found in the input string. Once I have the string determined, it's now in the buffer I would simply delete all the matched strings in the input string and the character pattern from the pattern string then recurse.

Apologies if my explanation wasn't very clear, I hope my code can be clear though.

Comment: Works for most cases, doesn't work for cases like "aba", "t1t12t1"

Comment: Also doesn't take into account the order of the split, "aba", "bluebluegreen" is true when it should be false.

Comment: I think if we can fix the ordering and fixing cases like "t1t12t1" this solution would be perfect.

Comment: Does it work for this case? isMatch("aba", "bluegreenblube") -> true